# How to edit a file in gedit?

Tags: gedit

I'm trying to mount an hdd , by editing the `/etc/fstab` file using gedit. I'm aiming to edit incorrect line (using UUID) and got a detailed error message. I now have the correct line to insert in the file.

Just learning how to use gedit. Do a have to do anything other than input the correct line. Please.

Comment: What did I just read?! What are you trying to do? Mount an hdd? Use gedit for what?

Comment: Sorry, it's totally unclear what you're asking. Gedit is a text editor, this has nothing to do with mounting partitions or UUIDs. Did you mean Gparted or something like that? Or do you mean editing the file `/etc/fstab` that configures automatically mounted partitions with Gedit? Please clarify what you mean and if there are Error messages etc, show them to us. We can#t help you if we don't understand your problem.

Comment: hi Tanks for the response . Sorry im still learning the language. I was editing the file in /ect/fstab

Comment: No, just input the correct line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use gedit, open a terminal : <kbd>strg</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type `gksu gedit /etc/fstab`.

If `gksu` ist not installed run `sudo apt-get install gksu` to install it.

An alternative would be using an command line editor like `nano`, in the terminal type: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.